# include dlib in ros cmake files

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, dlib

I want to use some dlib opencv headers in the pub-sub application of ros. I tried to include the dlib libraries in the ros-package cmake files as follows:

**My dlib installation source path:** /home/xxxx/computervision/dlib-18.18/dlib

So I included it in cmake file of ros-pkg the following way:

"
set (dlib_DIR   "/home/praneeth/computervision/dlib-18.18/dlib/")
find_package(dlib 18.18 REQUIRED)
"
(went through the similar way of including a opencv library inside ros-pkg cmake)

But I am facing with the error:

"
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "dlib" (requested
  version 18.18) with any of the following names:

```
dlibConfig.cmake
dlib-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "dlib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "dlib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "dlib"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
"

Even though the dlib folder of the above source path has **dlibConfig.cmake.in** file in it.

Any help on how to include these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this!! This reference [sourceforge.net/p/dclib/discussion/442517/thread/efc8d59d](http://sourceforge.net/p/dclib/discussion/442517/thread/efc8d59d) gave me a hint to look into dlib/examples/CMakeLists.txt and follow the same. Since, I know my dlib installation path, I simply included in my project (external to dlib source tree) CMakeLists.txt, the following code `include(dlibsourcepath_until_cmake)` and while compiling a program in my project, i have added dlib as one of its target link libraries as

```
target_link_libraries(program_executable_name ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} dlib)
```